# Get the maximum core frequency in Linux kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, driver, cpu

I am interested in obtaining the maximum frequency of a core without using the API offered by `"cpufreq" (cpufreq_quick_get_max(cpu))` rather using architecture-dependent code. The value returned by the "cpufreq" function is zero at boot time.

Comment: That depends on the architecture, and you'd have to do exactly the same that the architecture code does (once it has been registered).